# Why did clearing my global environment in RStudio fix my ggplot missing axis problem?

Tags: ggplot2, graphics, package, rstudio, ggtern

**My initial problem:**

In plots I created using ggplot, which functioned properly for months, the axis text was suddenly missing... unless I used ggsave. Of note, upon opening the project, if I tried to view a plot, I got the following error:

```
Error in eval(`_inherit`, env, NULL) : object 'ScalesList' not found
```

Only by rerunning the code to generate the plot could I see anything at all. Only the axis text (ticks, tick labels, and axis labels) was missing (on both the x and y axes). These were plots that worked fine one day then stopped working the next with no changes to the code.

**What I tried:**

I tried dev.off() and a variety of related options, none of which had any effect. I updated RStudio, which made no difference. My plots looked fine in a new project. I detached all unnecessary packages and reattached them one by one. I updated out-of-date packages. Basic troubleshooting.

**What finally solved the problem:**

Eventually, I cleared all of the objects from my workspace (the global environment) so that I could, in a sense, start over again. That's when my plots began working again. In the plot panel, the axis text appeared again.

**My question:**

Wuh? Why did this work? I've only had this problem one or two times in the past few years (although not on the same computer with the same set up). In the past, dev.off() fixed the problem. Although my problem is already solved, I would like to understand what happened. Seeking insights and new knowledge and perhaps avenues for resolution next time I run into this problem. What is stored in the global environment which influences the RStudio graphics device? Does the ScalesList error provide a clue?

**Possibly relevant:**

Weeks before my plots stopped working, I had installed the latest version of ggtern, an extension to ggplot2 that creates ternary diagrams. I had also written a function for creating specific plots, and in that function, I removed the axis text. However, I was not using this function in the plots which stopped working. I also had ggpubr and ggmaps installed.

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint exactly what the problem is, but restarting R every so often and re-running the code is a good habit to do, as it helps to ensure a reproducible workflow. You generally don't need to use dev,off() - but if you find yourself in such a situation, I'd first recommend restarting R instead of running that command.

Comment: I did restart R multiple times, but that is good advice!

Comment: NP - If you do get this error after restarting R and running your script fresh, then I would suggest providing a minimally reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: This comment on ggplot's github might be relevant for the ggtern comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3561#issuecomment-599091916

Comment: @teunbrand, I think you nailed it. In fact, I ran into other problems using ggplot after installing ggtern and ended up recreating the ternary diagrams myself using custom functions. I think an issue between ggtern and ggplot2 is the most likely culprit. It's a shame... ggtern would otherwise be a great resource. Thanks so much for the link!

Comment: Yeah it is as Claus mentioned, ggtern changes a few things about ggplot's internal workings. These are build upon environments and these are not copy-on-modify but modify-in-place, which can become problematic. But @Phil's comment is also true, try to start with fresh R environments. You might like Jenny Bryan's talk on this topic from 06:00 onward https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable/.